# ¿Como deshabilitar horario de verano central en NodeJS?

Tags: nodejs, timezone

En casi todo el territorio Mexicano fue eliminado el horario de verano por lo que estoy teniendo problemas con una aplicacion OnPremise de NodeJS y Windows a continuacion muestro el siguiente conflicto:
Todas y cada una de las aplicaciones de NodeJS corren con el horario de verano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en el sistema operativo Windows Server 2016, Windows 10, Edge, Chrome
Consola Edge:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Windows:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que puedo manejar los datos con librerias de terceros o en su caso convertir a UTC el detalle es el tiempo que me costaria invertir ademas cada columna registros y demas.

¿Sabran alguna manera de deshabilitarlo?

He tratado de cambiar la zona horaria sin embargo no he tenido exito.
Gracias

Comment: Hola. Pudiste solucionarlo? Creo que este problema es más de las configuraciones del servidor que de nodejs. Revisa la hora que tiene configurada y trata de deshabilitar el horario de verano.